# Is this a valid proof for the supremum subsequential limit $\geq$ lim sup?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Let the supremum subsequential limit be $L$. Assume the contrary, that $L< \lim \sup$.
Write $L +2 \epsilon= \lim \sup$ for $\epsilon >0$.

- If there are only finitely many $i$ such that $a_i \geq L+ \epsilon$, then consider the maximum such $i$, say $M$. Then $\forall n\geq M+1$, $a_n <L+\epsilon \implies \forall u >M, \  \sup_{n \geq u} a_n \leq L+ \epsilon \implies \lim \sup \leq L +\epsilon$. Contradiction.
- If there are infinitely many $i$ such that $a_i \geq L+ \epsilon$, then construct a sequence of such $a_i$s say $(a_{k_i})$. Of course, $a_i$ is bounded above so $(a_{k_i})$ is a bounded sequence. By Bolzano Weierstrass, it has a convergent subsequence, whose limit $\ell \geq L+ \epsilon > L$. Contradiction since $L$ is the supremum subsequential limit.

We will also show the supremum subsequential limit exists.
Take any convergent subsequence $(a_{k_i}) \rightarrow t$. Since $k_i \geq i$ for all $i$,
$\sup_{n \geq i}a_n \geq a_{n_i}\ \ \forall i$. This implies  $\lim \sup \geq t$. 
So all subsequential limits are bounded above by $\lim \sup \implies$ $L$ exists and $\lim \sup \geq L$. Combining with the previous inequality, $L = \lim \sup$.

Comment: Have you already proved that there **is** a greatest subsequential limit?

Comment: Yes. Take any convergent subsequence $(a_{k_i}) \rightarrow t$. Since $k_i \geq i$ for all $i$,
 $\sup_{n \geq i}a_n \geq a_{n_i}\ \ \forall i$. This implies  $\lim \sup \geq t$.

Comment: That doesn’t actually prove that there is a greatest subsequential limit: it merely shows that the subsequential limits are bounded above by the $\limsup$. If you haven’t actually proved that the set of subsequential limits has a maximum and not just a supremum, you’ll need to modify your argument a bit: in that case you can’t call $L$ the greatest subsequential limit, but you **can** assume that it’s the supremum of the subsequential limits and derive the same contradiction. Then you can conclude that the supremum of the subsequential limits is $\ge\limsup$.

Comment: Oh I see. So I will try to prove the following claim:
Let $l_n$ be a sequence of subsequential limits. If $l_n \rightarrow l$ then $l$ is also a subsequential limit. I hope this resolves it. :)

Comment: Yes, that’s the key piece; if you prove that, you’re fine. It’s a little messy but not terribly hard.

Comment: Ok, I proved it but there is too much notation in my proof that will be hard to LATEX. (The idea is from each subsequence who's limit is $l_{k_i}$, choose an index large enough from this subsequence so that $|l_{k_i} - l| < 1/k$.) 

Hence, I edited the question to proving the supremum subsequential limit $\geq \lim \sup$.

Comment: Yes, that idea works, and your argument looks good now.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is an alternative valid proof to show the supremum subsequential limit exists. Suppose the set of subsequential limits is unbounded above. Let's suppose the original sequence (a_n) is bounded above by $B$. Take a subsequential limit $>B+1$. Then $\exists a_i$ such that $|a_i -B-1|<1 \implies a_i >B$. Contradiction.

Comment: Yes, it’s easy to get boundedness; the harder part is showing that the set of subsequential limits is closed, so that boundedness implies the existence of a maximum element.

Comment: Thank you very much @BrianM.Scott. Your feedback was very helpful. Cheers :)

Comment: You’re very welcome!